# Adding different values to line chart after each time running

Tags: android

i'm getting line chart using aChart engine , but in my application i want add values dynamically 1st run x=1 and in second run x=4. i want to show 1 as well 4 in my graph, graph showing current value i'e 4 on the graph, (can i use shared preference) i need to add list of values in the x-axis, I'll be great full for any help in regards this

Answer (score 0):

When you are specifically pairing (x, y) values, you add values for x-arrays and corresponding y-arrays.

Like:

```
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
x.add(new double[] { 1, 4, 7, 11, 15, 19});
```

and corresponding y-values will be:

```
List<double[]> y = new ArrayList<double[]>();
y.add(new double[] { 100, 500, 600, 800, 1000, 1200});
```

This is done in class AverageTemperatureChart in aChartEngine.

The values pairs would be (1, 100), (4, 500), (7, 600), (11, 800), (15, 1000) and (19, 1200).

Hope this is helps you out.